# Regex alteration behaving greedily

Tags: regex

I am not sure if I can call this greedy but here is a simple regex pattern with alterations.

- Regex Pattern:  `val|get|valueget|eva`
- Text Input:     `aevalueget`

In my understanding it should match "val" because val is the left most expression in the pattern and it takes precedence. since there is a matching substring in Input it should match "val" and should stop searching further.
But the match in the above case is "eva" which is the right most expression in the pattern.
In fact all the expressions in the patter has a matching substring in the Input but seems like it chooses the right most expression in the pattern.
I am trying to make sense of this. It would be really great if someone can explain this behaviour.

Comment: The regex processor finds `eva` before it finds `val`.

Comment: yeh it seems like it does but why..
since there is OR shouldnt it try matching the whole first expression and then going to the next expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the regex processor is moving down the string a step at a time trying to find matches.  Since `eva` is leftmost in the string, it is found before any comparison at the subsequent `val`.

Instead of imagining that the regular expression engine is searching the whole string for `val`, then for `get`, then for `valueget`, then for `eva`, it works more like this:

```
|aevalueget
```

Starting here, it does not match `val`, so it checks `get`, then `valueget`, then `eva`.  None of those match, so it moves to the next position:

```
a|evaluget
```

Starting here, it's doesn't match `val`, `get`, or `valueget`, but it *does* match `eva`, so the regular expression has been matched.

Comment: Note that a tool like `grep` or `awk` will return the larger result, that is `valueget`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions by their very nature don't take precedence like you want them too.  They just iterate over the string, and try to build up matches as they see them.

If you want to match `val` before `eva` in `eval`, then you need to run 2 regular expressions, 1 after the other.  the first one for `val` and the second one for `eva`

Comment: or if your regex flavor supports lookarounds, `/valueget|val|get|eva(?!l)/`

Comment: I thought the use of OR "|" is to match seperately..
First expression OR second expression
try matching First expression if not a match then try matching second expression... isn't this right?